# Deleting rows from list one if they appear in list 2

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two worksheets:

Sheet 1

```
apples   5   red
pears    4   green
oranges  7   orange
```

Sheet 2

```
apples
bananas
raspberries
```

I need to do some sort of look up that compares the lists and deletes any in list 2, from list one, so I would be left with:

```
pears   4 green
oranges 7 orange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [`this`](http://www.ablebits.com/excel-remove-duplicates/compare-tables-duplicates.php). I think this is helpfull for you